# Getting a user's log-in date from who command

Tags: bash, unix

I've been trying to get only the date a user logged in in bash.

I tried using

```
who | grep 'user'
```

which gives me the data for the user just fine. I've been unsuccessful at getting a string containing the date the user logged in, however:

```
who | grep 'user' | cut -f3
```

doesn't work for some reason.

I tried to use a space as a delimiter, but which field to cut would vary depending on the length of the username:

```
who | grep 'user' | cut -d ' ' -f12
```

would give me the date for usernames of a fixed length, but would give me a different field for usernames of different lengths.

It looks like the delimiter is a tab as the number of spaces between the first and second fields changes depending on the length of the username. I tried specifying the delimiter as a tab (even though cut assumes it is), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `awk` instead of `cut`, you can even get `awk` to do the filtering `grep` is currently doing:

```
who | awk '/user/{print $3}'
```

The use of `$3` means that the 3rd column of the data will be output. Awk's default field separator is a [sequence of whitespaces](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html#Default-Field-Splitting).

Using `awk` to replace only your `cut` command (and not `grep`) would result in:

```
who | grep 'user' | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: Would upvote if you promoted the second variant as the primary answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` or some other tool less bothered by multiple delimiters than `cut`.

```
who | awk '{print $3}'
```